# Docker build. command is failing in my machine

Tags: docker, redis

**I am trying to build a docker and it is giving me below exception. Any idea what could be wrong**

First Day with the docker so my question could be bit out of sync

```
docker build . 
[+] Building 1.2s (5/5) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Docker file                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                                                                       0.5s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:234cb88d3020898631af0ccbbcca9a66ae7306ecd30c9720690858c1b007d2a0                                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [2/2] RUN apk add --update redis                                                                                                                                                             0.6s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 > [2/2] RUN apk add --update redis:                                                                                                                                                                        
#5 0.171 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz                                                                                                                     
#5 0.364 281472913525832:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:                                                                
#5 0.365 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: Permission denied                                                                                                                         
#5 0.365 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main: No such file or directory                                                                                                      
#5 0.366 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/aarch64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
#5 0.536 281472913525832:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1913:
#5 0.538 ERROR: https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: Permission denied
#5 0.538 WARNING: Ignoring https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community: No such file or directory
#5 0.538 ERROR: unable to select packages:
#5 0.541   redis (no such package):
#5 0.541     required by: world[redis]



# Use an exisiting docker image as a base
From alpine

# Download and install a dependency
Run apk add --update redis

#Tell the image what to do when it starts as a container
CMD ["redis-server"]
```

Comment: You seem to have issues establishing an SSL connection to the package repositories. I just  tried and it worked for me. Can you try again to see if it was a temporary error?

Comment: If you just need to create a Redis over Alpine Linux Docker image, you can use the Redis official pre-built image from DockerHub, https://hub.docker.com/_/redis. For a quick start, simply type `docker run -p 6379:6379 redis:alpine`

Comment: Certificate failure could be a proxy intercepting the connection. If you have an internal CA certificate, you'll need to configure that first.

Comment: Yes. it was a proxy intercepting my connection.Thanks everyone